# Embedded objects in Word document

Tags: ms-word, ole

Embedded objects inside word document display contents only as long as they are opened on the source system. If you mail that to someone who opens on his system it just displays icon no contents.
Is there a way to resolve this so that anyone on any  system should be able to double click the embedded object (say for example word doc within main word doc) and be able to view its contents. As of now if just displays as an icon no contents if viewed on any other system.

Comment: "Embedding" means "Object linking & embedding" - OLE. OLE requires an OLE Server - the software that provides the service for displaying and editing content - and an OLE client that can consume what the OLE Server offers. The OLE Server is *required* - the person to whom you email a document with embedded content must have a program that can "host" the embedded object, otherwise only an icon can be displayed.

Comment: Thanks Cindy for the repsonse.
Now just let me explain this in another way. Lets say i prepared a word doc today and inside that wod doc inserted another word doc somewhere which has some contents. This other word doc i picked somewhere from my system. Now when i double click to open this other word doc when i am into my parent word doc, it easily opens displaying all contents as a word doc should display.
However if i mail the word doc to someone who opens on his system and then tries to double click it, he just sees void doc displayed as icon.I'm not sure what this OLE server and client do

Comment: If the person does not have Word installed then he cannot read the embedded object. In the background, *Word* opens this document. If the user has Word, then you need to make sure you're not embedding the document with a *link*. If you're linking, then the original document stays with you, it's not copied in.

Comment: So what happens in my case is that say i prep a word doc A and inside that simply use insert->object->from file-> display as icon.
Now i can double click and view the contents of the embedded word doc fine on my system. But when i mail it to someone who opens it on his system, that embedded word doc turns out to be just an icon.He can open the original word doc and view everything else there. Its not the matter of not having word installed, everyone of us has it installed. This turns out to be little weird, because then embedded objects do not serve any purpose. Any suggestions here.

Comment: I originally thought, since you're asking on Stack OVerflow, that programming code was involved, somehow. Since your question doesn't involve any programming, it belongs in an end-user forum. I've provided what background information I have on OLE, but I don't know why you're seeing this behavior. Be sure to include the version of Word involved, when you ask somewhere like Super User or on Microsoft Answers.